# Angular JS functions with multiple parameters

Tags: angularjs, factory

In my angular factory I have 3 functions that return the names of some codes, depending on their type: eat, feel and source. This is one of the functions

```
   getFeelingCode: function(feelingCode) {
        var feelTag=$filter('filter')(constant.feeling_code, {code: feelingCode}, function(a, b) {
          return a === b;
        });
      if(feelTag[0])
         return feelTag[0].label;
      else
         return feelingCode;
     }
```

The 3 functions bassically do the same thing, and I would like to convert them into one function, that would look like this:

```
vApp.factory('BgsFactory', function(constant, $filter) {
  return {  
      getCode: function(Code, StringCode) {
        var cst; 
        switch(StringCode) {
          case "eating_code": cst = constant.eating_code; break;
          case "feeling_code": cst = constant.feeling_code; break;
          case "source_code": cst = constant.source_code; break;
        }
        var Tag=$filter('filter')(cst, {code: Code}, function(a, b) {
          return a === b;
        });
      if(Tag[0])
         return Tag[0].label;
      else
         return Code;
    }
```

In my view I'm calling them like that

```
 <td>{{getSourceCode(item.tags.source)}}</td>
   <td>{{getEatingCode(item.tags.eat_code)}}</td>
   <td>{{getFeelingCode(item.tags.feeling_code)}}</td>
```

But I don't know how to set them in my controller. I tried something like that, but it fails saying that the functions don't exist.

```
$scope.getEatingCode = BgsFactory.getCode("eating_code");
$scope.getFeelingCode = BgsFactory.getCode("feeling_code");
$scope.getSourceCode = BgsFactory.getCode("source_code");
```

How should I pass the params?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I wasn't get is wrong, would be like this

```
$scope.getEatingCode = function(code) { return BgsFactory.getCode(code, "eating_code"); };
$scope.getFeelingCode = function(code) { return BgsFactory.getCode(code, "feeling_code"); };
$scope.getSourceCode = function(code) { return BgsFactory.getCode(code, "source_code"); };
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. It works, thank you!